# MS Access - Track changes made to existing table into another table (using table datasheet view - not form)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I want to be able to track any changes made to any of the fields in an existing table. The scenario is as follows:

- the user opens the datasheet view for an existing table in MS Access 2007/2010
- updates values in 2 fields and 5 rows (10 cells)
- saves the table (overwrites it)

I want to be able to push the changes (10 changes/rows) to a new table and then be able to open it in datasheet view to refer to it. Is there a way I can do this in access without using form?

Answer (score 1):

In 2010 and later you can use data macros, or what often other systems called table triggers.

You cannot in 2007.

Keep in mind that your use of the term “save table” is VERY wrong in the context here. In fact VERY wrong in the context of most databases. The user does not “save” the table.

You can ONLY edit ONE ROW at a time in a datasheet.  When you move off that record then the ROW is saved (not the table). , and if you move off, then the record is saved.

In 2010 and later, you have use of table procedure code. This thus will allow one to use a table trigger.

So 2010 and later does support table triggers and store procedure code. But since your question in includes Access 2007, then my suggestion to use table triggers (called data macros) may not work unless you can restrict users to 2010 and beyond.

In the follow example, when a user updates a row, then a “audit” table is updated with the user information. The function fosusername() is in fact a VBA function. This code is called from the before change update event for the table.

[image]

Of course the problem here is the VERY basis of your question assumes that users save a table – they don’t, they edit + save “single” records, or a single row at a time. So figuring “out” how a user is done would certainly be a challenge. So while code can be run when the users edit data, having table code run “when” the user closes the table is not possible.

As the end of the day, it likely best you create a datasheet that looks just like the table, and then change a few settings to “lock down” and prevent the user from using tables directly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no solution for this without using a form. I do not know of events (like a change or dirty event) for the actual data tables.

In a form you could use the dirty property to make sure you fetch the data. You can make the form look like a datahseet with `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDatasheetView` or set the form in datasheet view on default.